# .htaccess Rewrite Rules redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, redirect

I'm trying to configure my .htaccess to point any URL that looks like this:

```
DOMAIN/something
```

To this URL:

```
DOMAIN/index.php?title=something
```

Yet to keep the original URL in the browser.

I've tried doing so:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^/(. *)$  /index.php?title=$1
```

But it didn't work

Comment: I am not sure if it is just a typo here on SO, or if you really have a space between your `.` and `*`, but that regex won't do what you want. Try: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding RewriteRule flag with your redirecting rule using [R].
Use of the [R] flag causes a HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser. Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax like [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is specified. [R=301] is for redirect user to a new location.

Instead of this

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^/(. *)$  /index.php?title=$1
```

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^/(. *)$  /index.php?title=$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP asked for.  They said `keep the original URL in the browser`. `R` issues an external redirect and the browser URL will change.